# Jquery User input into JSON

Tags: jquery, json, encode

I have a complex form that the user has some selections to make and also a few textareas to fill in with info.  The form works great and the data is passed via JSON to my MVC controller and all works fine.

However users being users I have found that some are using special chars like "£$%&() etc and these are causing the JSON to be formatted incorrectly so the Controller Action is not binding correctly.

SO my question is how can I encode the text input from the user so that it will form valid JSON.

Current way I collect the data is:

```
var TelNo = $("#TelNo").
var EmailMessage = $("#EmailMessage").val();
```

Thanks.

Cliff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no real function for escaping characters for json.

A function to do this would be something like this

```
function makeSafe(jsonf){
  jsonf= JSON.stringify(jsonf);
  jsonf = jsonf.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
                                      .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
                                      .replace(/\\"/g, "\\"")
                                      .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
                                      .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
                                      .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
                                      .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
                                      .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
  return jsonf;
}
```

Then you could do

```
EmailMessage  = makeSafe(EmailMessage);
```

I have added it to my string object like below so I can reference it when ever I need

```
String.prototype.makeSafe= function() {
    return this.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, "\\"")
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
};
var EmailMessage = $("#EmailMessage").val()
EmailMessage = EmailMessage.makeSafe();
```

Comment: Brilliant I was just starting down this track but you have a perfect solution thanks.